# how I can run an electron app on Ubuntu 18.04 ( I have only the binary )

Tags: electron

[image: the app directory]

I copied this application from one Pc to an other,both have Ubuntu 18.04, and I want to know what I need to run it, I don't have the source only those files ?
I tried to 'chmod' for the eGestion app but when I click on it nothing happens. 
thanks for any possible help.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have picked up an application meant for Macintosh, it does not work to just copy an Application folder or installed App to ubuntu and try to run it.

the Application has been compiled for a specifict target, it will not work for a whole other target for which there is a whole seperate compilation process.

Comment: that what I was thinking, but as I said before the application was created originally for Ubuntu and it work fine in the other workstation

Comment: that's because they build for ubuntu as well. get the ubuntu package or installer. what is the application called? if it's part of ubuntu's repositories then you can simply in a terminal type (addapt the name) `sudo apt install myapp` if it is published under a PPA the you could `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:some/ppa -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install myapp`

Comment: no it's not a part of the repositories, it's a custom application created by someone to a friend company, and he failed into a lot of things, now I'm just trying to open it to see what they need and re design it from scratch, electron was never my thing .

Comment: ok well you'll need the ubuntu build. was there a jenkins building the project? did it bundle the builds for mac linux and windows into a single zip?

Answer (score 0):

try open a terminal and run it from there

```
./eGestion.app
```